# Distributing distinct apples among 5 people

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to distribute 6 distinct apples among 5 people? How would I do this? I know for identical it would b C(6 + 5 - 1, 6).

Comment: For identical apples there's only one way to distribute them.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: If they're all considered identical, then no matter which apple goes to which person, nothing changes, it's the same distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each apple has $5$ possibilities for the person it goes to.  There are $6$ apples.

So you might think of $$5 \times 5 \times 5 \times 5 \times 5 \times 5.$$

Comment: Wouldn't this assume each person gets only 1? This wouldn't distributing them, or am I wrong?

Comment: @gandolf:  If each person only got one apple, then there would be an apple left over and so the attempt would have failed.  Try a smaller example yourself such as $3$ distinct apples and $2$ distinct people: you should get $8$ possible distributions of the apples

Comment: Oh, okay, I got it confused with 6^5.